# Scheduling SQL backups with laravel outside storage path

Tags: php, laravel

I know it's possible to schedule commands to be run with laravel and cron job, my goal is tro create a command to backup my sql databases into my home directory inside my VPS, the example I found uses laravel storage path to drop the backups but I was wondering how can I choose another file outside my laravel app folder (my user home directory for example), is it possible to do?

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

class BackupDatabase extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'db:backup';

    protected $description = 'Backup the database';

    protected $process;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->process = new Process(sprintf(
            'mysqldump -u%s -p%s %s > %s',
            config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
            config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
            config('database.connections.mysql.database'),
            storage_path('backups/backup.sql')
        ));
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $this->process->mustRun();

            $this->info('The backup has been proceed successfully.');
        } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {
            $this->error('The backup process has been failed.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to put a full custom path like '/home/backups/' instead of storage_path()?

Comment: The user used to run the cronjobs needs to be able to write in your home directory though.